# The Axiom of Choice is independent from the Ordering Principle in set theory with atoms

Tags: set-theory, solution-verification, axiom-of-choice

Here follows the final paragraph of section 4.5 in Jech's *Axiom of Choice* where he proves that AC is independent from the Ordering Principle in set theory with atoms:

> The ordering $<$ of $A$ is in $\mathcal{V}$ since the group $G$ consists of
>   order-preserving permutations and so $\text{sym}(<) = G$. The set $I$
>   consists of finite subsets of a linearly ordered set and thus can be
>   linearly ordered (lexicographically). Therefore the class $\text{On}
>  \times I$ can be linearly ordered (lexicographically again). And since
>   we have a symmetric one-to-one mapping of $\mathcal{V}$ into $\text{On} \times
>  I$, we obtain a linear ordering $<$ of $\mathcal{V}$, which is a symmetric
>   class. Thus every set can be linearly ordered in $\mathcal{V}$.

Let $A$ denote the set of atoms and $\mathcal{V}$ the permutation model.

I understand this as: there is a certain sentence $\varphi(x, y)$ such that we can prove that $\varphi$ represents a linear order of $\mathcal{V}$. That is, the collection $R$ of $\langle a, b \rangle$ such that $\varphi(a, b)$ forms a relation which satisfies the axioms of a linear order, where $a < b$ if $\langle a, b \rangle \in R$. To show this we use that there is a one-to-one mapping of $\mathcal{V}$ into $\text{On} \times I$ (represented by some formula).

Since in general for a sentence $\psi(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and a permutation $\pi$ of $A$ we have $\psi(x_1, \dots, x_n) \leftrightarrow \psi(\pi x_1, \dots, \pi x_n)$, it follows that $R$ is symmetric. Proof: for any $\pi$ and $\langle a, b \rangle \in R$ we have $\pi \langle a, b \rangle = \langle \pi a, \pi b \rangle$ and $a < b \Leftrightarrow \varphi(a, b) \Leftrightarrow \varphi(\pi a, \pi b) \Leftrightarrow \pi a < \pi b$, so that $\pi\langle a, b \rangle \in R$. Therefore $\pi [R] \subset R$, but also $\pi^{-1} [R] \subset R \Rightarrow R \subset \pi [R]$; that is, $\pi[R] = R$.

Because $R$ is symmetric, so is every $R_\alpha = R \cap \mathcal{P}^\alpha(A)$; that is, $R_\alpha \in \mathcal{V}$. Also, there will be some $\beta$ such that the linear order $(X, <) \subset R_\beta \in \mathcal{V}$. Therefore, by absoluteness, $\mathcal{V} \models X \text{ can be linearly ordered}$.

I'm really confused. Is this correct? But then I'm not using many of the things Jech mentions, such as that the ordering $<$ of $A$ is in $\mathcal{V}$, or that the one-to-one mapping of $\mathcal{V}$ into $\text{On} \times I$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping from $\mathrm{On}\times A^{<\omega}$ is amenable. In the sense that every subset is in the permutation model. If you assume some class theory with atoms instead, you get the full map. But for set theory it's not necessarily definable in a reasonable sense internally to the model.

If we assume there is a global well ordering of the kernel, though, then the map is definable.

---

Your way of understanding is just fine. Your confusion arises from the fact that you're delegating a lot of information to "there is a formula", instead of trying to understand this formula.

The idea is to ask what is the orbit of a set $x$ under the permutations in the group. We can enumerate the orbits (although each orbit may fail to have a well-ordering).

Next we ask what is the minimal support of $x$, and we note that since our permutations are order preserving, fixing pointwise a finite set is the same as stabilising it (i.e., no points are moved outside/into the set).

And so it means that two sets in the same orbit will have the same minimal support if and only if they are equal.

So the formula we use for the linear order depends on $A$ and its linear order, as well as a pre-existing formula which well-orders the entire universe.

The point I raised above is that it is consistent that there is no formula providing a well-ordering of the universe. But in that case we can always fix a well-ordering of a large enough $\mathcal P^\alpha(A)$ and work with that one to linearly order a given set $x$.

---

Finally, the reason you cannot take the formula defining a well-ordering is that this formula is not stable under your permutations. Indeed, there are two atoms $a,b$ such that $a<b$ in the linear order, but $b<_wa$ in the well-order defined by the formula (simply since $<$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$).

This means exactly that $\pi^n(a)$, where $\pi$ is any order automorphism such that $\pi(a)=b$, will define a strictly increasing countable set, and we can prove there are no such sets.

In this case you can ask yourself, instead, since $A$ **can** be well-ordered in the "full universe", why is it not well-orderable in $V$? And this well-ordering is definable with a parameter (e.g., itself).

The key problem, which is where Jech is a bit scruffy with the details, is that $\sf ZFC$ does not prove that there is a definable well-ordering. In which case there is no injection from $V$ into $\mathrm{On}\times A^{<\omega}$. But there is still an injection (in $V$) from any set into some $\alpha\times A^{<\omega}$, which is enough for the proof to go through.

Comment: I don't want to think about classes first. Let me first understand what happens with "normal" set theory. Is what I did the way to think about it, if I just want to show $V \models \forall X (X \text{ can be linearly ordered})$?

Comment: Yes, your edit is fine. I remember being thoroughly confused about the same issues at some point when I was learning this for the first or second time...

Comment: I'm just landing from a flight now. So this will have to wait for tomorrow morning, since I don't think i will have a proper keyboard in front of me before then. Maybe I'll end up typing something on the phone though... Let's see.

Comment: Well, that's very kind of you. I'm looking forward to your answer!

Comment: Alright, I've edited to clarify.

Comment: I've edited my question because I made an error: when I asked where $A \in \mathcal{V}$ is required I meant to say instead where we used that the ordering $<$ of $A$ is in $\mathcal{V}$. I'll reread what you wrote to see if I understand it now (in addition to the answer of KP Hart).

Comment: I think I understand it slightly better now. I posted some questions under KP Hart's answer, maybe it helps you understand where my confusion arises.

Comment: I hope that this will clarify, at last.

Comment: I don't think so... I really appreciate all your help and clarifications, but I am missing something more fundamental...

Comment: Yes. You are. My suggestion is to leave it now and come back after the weekend with fresh eyes. At this point I don't see how anything I can add can clarify. If nothing else, with fresh eyes you'll maybe manage to clarify better what is truly the missing point.

Comment: OK. I think the confusion stems from this: there seem to be two ways to me to look at the problem, and then there is also Global Choice which confuses me further. 1) Pick any $x \in \mathcal{V}$. Note that the order $<$ of $A$ is in $\mathcal{V}$. This and absoluteness show that for arbitrary large $\alpha$ the lexicographic order of $\alpha \times A^{< \omega}$ is in $\mathcal{V}$. Now using the symmetry of the map injecting $\mathcal{V}$ into $\text{On} \times I$, we also know that for some large enough $\alpha$ there is an injective map $x \to \alpha \times I$ which is in $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: Yes, and where is the confusion?

Comment: This shows $\mathcal{V} \models x \text{ can be linearly ordered}$. The second way to look at it : 2) Again pick some $x \in \mathcal{V}$ and directly look at the formula that represents the linear ordering of a large enough part of $\mathcal{V}$ to include $x \times x$; this can be done without involving Global Choice I think. Like KP mentioned this formula looks like $\psi(x, y, <)$ with no further parameters. The order defined by $\psi(x, y, <)$ is symmetric because in general $\psi(x, y, <) \leftrightarrow \psi(\pi x, \pi y, \pi(<))$ and $\pi(<) = \; <$. And so we are again done.

Comment: Yes, that much is true. And that is what I kept repeating in my answer. You don't need the global choice part if you're willing to do things set wise.

Comment: The confusion arises with me because Jech seems to hint at the second approach by stating _"we obtain a linear ordering $<$ of $\mathcal{V}$, **which is a symmetric class**."_ But at the same time he starts out with the first approach. And then there was also the issue of Global Choice, which I am not very familiar with. To show Global Linear Ordering in $\mathcal{V}$ would we need to exhibit a formula $\varphi(x, y)$ of which $\mathcal{V}$ can show that it is a linear order for any input $x,y$?

Comment: As I said at the beginning, he tacitly assumes a class set theory in the background there. And as you may guess by now, for a global linear ordering you'd need some sort of global choice on the kernel, and it would still depend on the parameter which is the linear ordering of the atoms.

Comment: My deepest sympathies for you. The best advice I can offer is to let it go for now and come back to this issue in a year. Honestly.

Comment: If both approaches I just gave are correct for showing $\mathcal{V} \models x \text{ can be linearly ordered}$ then I'm happy for now and can blame Jech for my confusion (lol). When I've learned something more about class theory I'll come back to this issue of global linear order. I want to be a set theorist as well :x

Comment: Thanks for all your help and time :)

Comment: Well, you're on the right path, that's for sure!

Answer (score 1):

The definition or the order involves the formula that defines the injective map and the ordering $ < $ of $A$. The ultimate defining formula not only has the free variables $x$ and $y$ but also a parameter: the ordering of $\mathcal{V}$ that you define depends on the ordering of $A$ and that features as a parameter in that formula. For every possible linear order of $A$ you get a linear order of $\mathcal{V}$, but to prove that that global order is symmetric you need an order of $A$ that is already in $\mathcal{V}$.
So the formula looks like $\psi(x,y,<)$ and to show that the order is symmetric you must show that $\psi(\pi(x),\pi(y),<)$ holds whenever $\psi(x,y,<)$ holds (notice: no $\pi(<)$ in the formula). In the Mostowski model this is true because $\pi(<)={<}$ for all $\pi\in G$.

Comment: Oh I see, I missed that there was a hidden parameter $<$. So I was proving (in your notation) that $\psi(\pi(x), \pi(y), \pi(<))$, whereas I should have proved $\psi(\pi(x), \pi(y), <)$. But this can be saved since $\pi(<) = \; <$ anyway.

Comment: But this leaves open the question where we use that the one-to-one mapping of $V$ into $\text{On} \times I$ is symmetric.

Comment: Maybe I am now even more confused: what is stopping us from taking the global well order represented by some formula $\alpha(x, y)$ (we assumed global choice to order the orbits) and say that it is symmetric because $\alpha(x, y) \leftrightarrow \alpha(\pi x, \pi y)$? Surely this is absurd because it would mean that every set in $\mathcal{V}$ can be well-ordered, but $A$ cannot be well-ordered in $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: @Jori:The formula defining the injective map is part of the formula defining the order, so if it is not symmetric, chances are the the order is not symmetric either.

Comment: @Jori: the global well-order is symmetric, but not hereditarily so: it orders all members of the big universe, so not all of its elements are symmetric. Plus: it may involve non-symmetric sets as parameters, just as above. So it is not a given that it is usable in the permutation model.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, I must be missing something much more fundamental. There is a formula $\alpha(x, y)$ that well-orders the "full universe", and any formula of set theory ultimately only involves $\in$, so assume this for $\alpha$. Now take the permutation model $\mathcal{V}$ and consider the collection $C = \{(x, y) \in \mathcal{V} \times \mathcal{V} : \alpha(x, y) \}$. We have $\mathcal{V} \times \mathcal{V} \subset \mathcal{V}$, so $C \subset \mathcal{V}$ and for any permutation $\pi[C] \subset C$ because $\alpha(x, y) \leftrightarrow  \alpha(\pi x, \pi y)$. What's wrong?

Comment: Furthermore, I don't get why Jech says "[...] _Therefore_ the class $\text{On} \times I$ can be linearly ordered". I mean, of course it can be linearly ordered, we have a global well-order after all. Or does Jech mean that $\text{On} \times I$ can be linearly ordered **inside** $\mathcal{V}$?

Comment: @Jori: It can be linearly ordered whenever $I$ can be linearly ordered. Because it's a lexicographical product of two linear orders. And since $I$ can be linearly ordered inside $V$, the product can too.

Comment: @Jori: There are **no** parameter-free formulas which well-order the set of atoms, let alone the whole universe. There *can be* formulas which well-order the whole universe *with* a parameter which is a well-ordering of the set of atoms.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Maybe you can clarify then what the global choice axiom looks like (then I'll leave it until tomorrow, I really need fresh eyes :P). I was in the understanding that all axioms ultimately have some representation in the language of set theory, which only involves $\in$.

Comment: @Jori: Global Choice, in this case, would be something that looks like $\varphi(x,y,f)$ such that $f$ is a bijection of $A$ with $\omega$, and $\varphi(x,y,f)$ holds for exactly one $x\in y$ for every set $y$. Or equivalently, $\varphi$ defines a well-ordering (again with $f$ as a parameter). Having a representation in the language of set theory does not mean "there are no parameters allowed". How do you think models like $L[x]$ or $L(A)$ are defined for arbitrary sets?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I only know about Global Choice in the context of $V=L$, when there is a formula $x <_L y$ in the language of set theory of which we can prove that it represents a well-order of $L$ (and so $V$). As far as I've understood there are no hidden parameters in this formula. So you're saying that when we do something like this for $\text{ZFA}$ there will necessarily be some parameter involved (your $f$), since otherwise my construction would go through? And your $\varphi(x, y, f)$ just says about this $f$ that it well-orders $\omega$.

Comment: @Jori: Yes, in the case of $V=L$, and slightly more general in the case of $V=\rm HOD$, there is a parameter-free formula which provably well-orders the universe. In the case of atoms, permuting the atoms defines an automorphism of the universe. But a well-ordered set has no non-trivial automorphisms, so a global well-order must be definable with parameters. You can reduce this to a parameter free well-ordering of the kernel (e.g., assume the kernel is $L$), but something has to be said about the atoms.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I can follow that. Only my last sentence I mistyped: I meant that you can prove something like "$\varphi(x, y, f)$ defines a well-order of the universe (in $x,y$) if $f$ is a bijection of $A$ with $\omega$". Then using the formula as a well-order is conditional upon providing an $f$ with the required property. I never thought of axioms incorporating parameters like this; although Global Choice isn't really an axiom in this situation but rather a consequence of some type of constructability axiom. Is this the correct way to think about it?